# has_one and has_many in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

How can I use `has_one` and `has_many` in codeigniter 3.0?

I would like to create relations through tables like in Ruby on Rails.

I.E

```
Class User
{
     has_many: comments
}

Class Comments
{
     belongs_to: users
}
```

Comment: Second option other than offered answer is using [MY_Model](https://github.com/avenirer/CodeIgniter-MY_Model) that firmly comprehends mentioned relations.

Answer (score 1):

This is the most common usage, and is used in almost every project. There is a simple pattern to defining this relationship.

Post has a creator and an editor, which may be different users. Here's how to set that up.

**Post**

```
class Post extends DataMapper {
    $has_one = array(
        'creator' => array(
            'class' => 'user',
            'other_field' => 'created_post'
        ),
        'editor' => array(
            'class' => 'user',
            'other_field' => 'edited_post'
        )
    );
}
```

**User**

```
class User extends DataMapper {
    $has_many = array(
        'created_post' => array(
            'class' => 'post',
            'other_field' => 'creator'
        ),
        'edited_post' => array(
            'class' => 'post',
            'other_field' => 'editor'
        )
    );
}
```

**A couple of things to note here.**

1. The relationship is now defined by the relationship key on either
   side, not the model name. This has now become the only way to look
   up the relationship.
2. The key on one side of the relationship becomes the other_field on
   the opposite side, and vice-versa.
3. Because we need a way to specify the difference between posts that
   were edited and those that were created, we have to declare the
   slightly unusual edited_post and created_post relationships. These
   could have any name, as long as they were unique and mirrored on
   Post.

> http://datamapper.wanwizard.eu/pages/advancedrelations.html